Manga I stumbled upon years ago where a boy sees numbers over heads indicating attraction level to him
Well I only read the first chapter and remember little about it.
Here is the list of what I can remember about the first chapter:

The main character, a boy, who's in highschool woke up in the morning.
When he went downstairs(the living or the kitchen) he saw his above his mom's head are numbers or percentage.
He couldn't believe what he was seeing and asked his mom.
His mom was puzzled and doesn't know what he's saying.
The number above mom's head is 70% or 75%
He went to school with his two childhood friends, one male, one female.
They also have numbers above their heads.
The numbers I remember above the girl friend's head is around 70%-75% or something.
Everyone they passed by or encountered has numbers or percentages above their heads.
Main character finally figured out that the numbers or percentages signifies how much people like/love him.
The three friends finally arrived at their classroom.
The boy thinks to himself that no one that he has encountered yet reached a percent above 90% or somewhere around there.
His seatmate, a girl, suddenly called out to him.
He's surprised cause the number above the girl/seatmate is 100%.
Chapter ends there.

Additional information I can add is;

The artstyle was good.
The seatmate has a short hair, dark.

Also, according to spoilers in the post's comments.

There are multiple girls who have 100% above their heads meaning multiple female leads.
The are around 4 FMLs if I remember correctly.
The seatmate's reason she fell in love with the main character was
because the MC picked up her eraser during a test or something.


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you tell us when and where you read this?

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rCZ9PvFvdkk this thing?

Dokuzakura?

Sorry, since I'm still new here I don't know how to reply to individual comments so I'll try to answer them all at once. And thank as well for the welcome!

I read it on a facebook group called wholesome manga some time during October of 2021 - May of 2022.
The youtube link and Dokazakura are unfortunately not it.


@HAZIMEMado You can use an @ sign to tag a person in a comment and they'll get notified. I think you can only tag one person that way in a comment.

I have that same thing, it's tough — it gets really boring just seeing 110% everywhere all day.

Was this in full color or black and white?

This sound like love parameter but only 2 FML

@FuzzyBoots Thank you for the info :). Gladly accepted, took too long to log back in here because I was busy dealing with life.

@qazmlpok Black and white, thank you for the inquiry, took too long to log back in here because I was busy dealing with life.

@someoneuseless Not the case sadly.

https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/11s6chm/disc_a_manga_about_the_mysterious_numbers_above/#lightbox (not really)

@FuzzyBoots Sadly, it's not it
